# Understanding tornado coroutine decorator + twitter authentication

Tags: python, asynchronous, twitter, tornado, coroutine

I am new to Tornado and trying to get simple OAuth twitter authentication working. As per the documention, I need to set up an authentication handler as follows:

```
class TwitterAuthHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.TwitterMixin):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument("oauth_token", None):
            user = yield self.get_authenticated_user()
            if not user:
                raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Twitter auth failed")
            self.set_secure_cookie("twitter_user", user)
            self.redirect("/")
        else:
            self.authenticate_redirect()
```

However, when I run this code I get the error:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 485, in redirect
    raise Exception("Cannot redirect after headers have been written")
Exception: Cannot redirect after headers have been written
```

This seems to be since the asynchronous call is not operating correctly, with the exception raised on the `self.authenticate_redirect()` line. If I replace `@tornado.gen.coroutine` with `@tornado.gen.engine` everything works fine. However, I understand that `gen.engine` is the old way of doing things, and `gen.coroutine` should be preferred as it returns a future.

I've also tried wrapping the call to `self.get_authenticated_user()` in `tornado.gen.Task()`. Am not sure when wrapping with `gen.Task()` is even necessary, but this does not seem to make any difference in this case.

What is wrong with this code, and why does `gen.coroutine` fail but `gen.engine` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking this I thought it's probably a bug. Posting example code into this thread of python-tornado Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/python-tornado/YypdSaXsM_Y confirmed it:

> The auth*_redirect methods don't return Futures so they can't be
>   yielded, but they should.  As a workaround for now you can continue to
>   use @gen.engine and call these methods without yielding.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting that this bug is still to be squashed despite being a problem with the code example featured in the Tornado documentation itself (see [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/auth.html#twitter)). However, it's good to know what the cause is and that I am not going crazy in my understanding of `gen.coroutine` vs `gen.engine`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: has this been fixed?

Comment: @evan54, apparently it was fixed in [version 3.1](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v3.1.0.html): "The authenticate_redirect and authorize_redirect methods in the tornado.auth mixin classes all now return Futures."